# About the environmental variables on different systems

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows

I've a problem with this statement:

```
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/MobileOrg")
```

It works in Linux (and maybe in OSX too), because the tilde is expanded in `/home/<me>/Dropbox/MobileOrg`. It doesn't in Windows, because emacs expand the tilde into `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\` while Dropbox refers to the `%USERPROFILE%` environmental variable, which is expanded into `C:\Users\<me>\`.

I already know I can use two different files depending to the OS, or introduce a condition. But I'm wondering if I can somehow avail of some variable I did not take in consideration. Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without testing it, what if you try: `(setenv "USERPROFILE" (or (getenv "USERPROFILE") (getenv "HOME"))`, and then write `(setq org-mobile-directory "$USERPROFILE/Dropbox/MobileOrg")`. I.e. Linux doesn't have `USERPROFILE` variable, so setting it would have no effect on anything else, but Emacs would know to expand it to the same path as your `HOME` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `%HOME%` to `c:\Users\<me>\`, and Emacs will then consider that your home directory. The downside is that you may have to move your `.emacs` to that directory too.

More information here:
 https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html

Answer (score 2):

You could check the system type and then set a variable that holds the location of your Dropbox directory on that platform.  For example:

```
(setq dropbox (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
                  (concat (file-name-as-directory (getenv "USERPROFILE"))
                          "Dropbox")
                "~/Dropbox"))
```

Once you've got that you can easily setup any other variables you need without them needing to know where the Dropbox actually is:

```
(setq org-mobile-directory (concat (file-name-as-directory dropbox)
                                   "MobileOrg"))
```

I use something like this to store all sorts of Emacs related stuff such bookmarks, abbreviations, and various bits of code.